# Two docker-compose file doesn't executing together in Linux

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, containers

I have recently containerized my friend's NODE project using `DOCKER` and `docker-compose`

`package.json`

```json
{
  "name": "moviesapi",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A moviesApI to handle movie search request of the customers",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "test": "mocha test/**/*.intg.js --exit",
    "dev": "nodemon index.js"
  },
  "author": "Flanker",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.0",
    "config": "^3.3.8",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "express-async-errors": "^3.1.1",
    "express-fileupload": "^1.4.0",
    "fawn": "^2.1.5",
    "file-upload": "^0.0.0",
    "helmet": "^6.0.0",
    "joi": "^17.6.3",
    "joi-objectid": "^4.0.2",
    "joi-password-complexity": "^5.1.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "mongodb": "^4.10.0",
    "mongoose": "^6.6.5",
    "router": "^1.3.7",
    "winston": "^3.8.2",
    "winston-mongodb": "^3.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "chai": "^4.3.6",
    "mocha": "^10.1.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20",
    "supertest": "^6.3.0"
  }
}
```

The `Dockerfile` look like

```
FROM node:16
ENV NODE_ENV=production
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ARG NODE_ENV=devlopment
ENV PORT=3000

COPY package*.json ./

RUN if [ "$NODE_ENV" = "production" ]; then npm ci --only=production; else npm install; fi
COPY . .

EXPOSE ${PORT}

RUN chown -R node /usr/src/app
USER node
CMD ["node", "index.js"]
```

The `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  app:
    image: moviesapi
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
      args:
        - NODE_ENV=production
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=production
      - PORT=3000
      - MONGO_URL=mongodb://mongo-db:27017/
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    depends_on:
      - mongo-db
    
  mongo-db:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - moviesapi-mongo-data:/data/db
volumes:
  moviesapi-mongo-data:
```

and for the development environment, The `docker-compose.dev.yml`

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  app:
    image: moviesapi
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
      args:
        - NODE_ENV=devlopment
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=devlopment
      - moviesApi_jwtPrivateKey=example_moviesApi_jwtPrivateKey
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules

    command: npm run dev
```

In my Windows machine when I am running `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.dev.yml up --build -d`
It works perfectly fine both in `PowerShell` and `WSL Ubuntu`

But when the same command I am running on my friend's PC which is a Ubuntu System. the log is saying nodemon is not there, and neither the bind mount is connected with the container.

So my guess is that the `docker-compose.dev.yml` is not getting executed using this command only the `docker-compose.yml` is executing. Don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

There's a typo on line 10 of your docker-compose.dev.yml file.

```
args:
        - NODE_ENV=devlopment
```

Because of this he probably falls back on default env and won't install the devDependencies.